# Probability of equilateral and right triangle built in a cube

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Having a standard cube:

1. Show that the triangle created by any three vertices can only be equilateral or right.
2. Calculate the probability that $3$ vertices forms a right triangle.
3. Excluding $3$ vertices and considering only the other $5$, calculate the probability $P$ that $3$ of the $5$ vertices form a right triangle. Say how many values $P$ can assume.

For the first point I don't understand how can I mathematically show it.

For the second point I've built manually the triangle on every face:
$$ \frac{6\cdot 4\cdot 2}{\binom{8}{3}} = \frac{6}{7}$$ but it's a try and I don't think it's right.

Being unsure on the second point, the third seems confusing to me.

Thanks to those who'll answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the third one, label the eight corners alternately black and white.
Any three black corners, or any three white corners, form an equilateral triangle.
Given five points, there are ${5\choose3}=10$ triangles.  How many of them are equilateral?  (It depends on the five points.)

Answer (score 1):

Realize the vertices of the cube by $C:=\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$. Let $T$ be a set of $3$ vertices in $C$. If there are two distinct vertices $v_1, v_2$ in $T$ with that $v_1, v_2$ differ only on one coordinate, then $T$ must be a right triangle, otherwise, $T$ must be an equilateral triangle.

For the second question, each equilateral triangle can be corresponded to a vertex which differs on exactly one coordinate with each vertex of the triangle, for instance, $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}\leftrightarrow(0,0,0)$. Hence, the answer is $\frac{\binom{8}{3}-8}{\binom{8}{3}}$.

The third question question is not clear to me as which three vertices are deleted, or they being deleted by random choice?

Comment: They're randomly deleted

Comment: Ok, if they are randomly deleted, how randomly? Just uniformly choose one such configuration from $\binom{8}{5}$? Or we flip a coin for each vertex, and accept those results each of which has 5 vertices chosen?

Comment: The vertex have each one the same probability of the others to be deleted,so i think $\binom{8}{5}$ is what is needed to choose the 5 vertex...